# How to Auto-Restart in JDeveloper?

Tags: java, ide, jdeveloper

In eclipse we have an option to `restart` the workspace using following option, <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Restart</kbd>.

[image]

But incase of JDeveloper, I didn't see such. How to `Auto-Restart` in `JDeveloper`?

**P.S:** FYI, I'm using `JDeveloper 12c`.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i'm doing so far. It seems like manual work. So we don't have any option to auto-restart?

Comment: I never felt I needed such an option in NetBeans. What is the reason for doing a thing like that?

Comment: The reason behind that, some times Eclipse IDE does't do auto code validation. If I had restart, it will do the trick. Since started to use JDeveloper for Oracle-MAF eager to know shortcuts and this kind of menus. It will help to do development smother as well as smarter.

Comment: So basically that shortcut exists in Eclipse since Eclipse has a bug that doesn't happen in JDev :-) If you are migrating to JDeveloper from Eclipse you can add keyboard mapping that are similar to Eclipse in the preferences under accelerators use the import.

Comment: Can you please explain/share the link for keyboard mapping in JDeveloper?